# Site "forgot" what the default template was

Tags: templates, default, index

I've had the same problem happen a few times, on several different EE sites, but I can't determine the cause so I'm turning to y'all.

Symptom: The site's main index page will fail to load and will display a blank white page with no output. When diagnosed, the problem turns out to be that the default template group "forgot" that it was the default template group. More specifically, the "is_site_default" field in the exp_templates table, was set to 'n' for all template groups. (In order to function, it has to be set to 'y' for one template group for each site you are running.)

Has anyone had this happen to them, and if so, do you know what causes it, so I can avoid it recurring?

Comment: Could it have to do something with clearing cache? Didn't had this before.

Comment: Seems like the default template group could be set via the config file and avoid that?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but no, it doesn't have anything to do with clearing the cache, and setting it via the config file is a good suggestion as a safer way to avoid having this happen, but it doesn't solve the question. Thanks!

Comment: Was the template group or template removed, and then restored by syncing from files perhaps?

Comment: Good thought, Derek, but no.  I suppose it's a mystery.

Comment: Hi Travis, could you run https://github.com/andrewfairlie/rc_debug and paste the output into GitHub Gist? If we know details about you're setup we might be able to crack this one...

Comment: If you are a SuperAdmin user you could go to the `CP > Admin > System Administration > Output and Debugging` and set the `Debug Preference` to 1, `Display Output Profiler?` to `Yes` and `Display Template Debugging` to `Yes`. That might help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Does this happen after core upgrades or fresh installs? Also can you indicate the rought version numbers for EE that we're talking about?? A fresh install doesn't have a default template until it is set manually, long shot but perhaps somethings getting updated/replaced during an update... Also, I don't suppose you're performing database backups or restores on a regular basis per chance?? Basically I'm asking what you think might cause the issue to happen, the trigger...

Comment: Its a shame this question has gone dead, it has many views. Travis, you could ressurect this! Have you got any further info for us, or been able to relaibly replicate it??

Comment: It happened on sites that were not recently updated; it has happened a few times (3 that I can remember) over the years, most recently in 2014, and it happens with sites at different version numbers.  I'm happy letting this one lie.

Answer (score -2):

If you go to Templates and then click on the Template Group that you wish to make the index template the default template and click on Edit Group for that template group then you will see a simple edit page come up which will allows you to change the Template Group Name and also there is a checkbox to enable just what you need there.